# What is the cause of "imbalanced" linkage disequilibrium?

Tags: genetics, population-genetics, genomics, allele

With perfect linkage disequilibrium ($D' = 1, R^2 = 1$), you might have the following table of counts for the alleles:

```
    B     b
A  100    0
a    0  100
```

With "partial" linkage disequilibrium ($D' < 1, R^2 < 1$), you'll see something like this:

```
    B     b
A  100   25
a   25  100
```

But I've sometimes seen the following "imbalanced" linkage disequilibrium ($D' = 1, R^2 < 1$):

```
    B     b
A  100    0
a   50  100
```

What gives rise to this sort of situation, where *aB* occurs, but *Ab* never does? Is there a name for this phenomenon? Which is a better measure of linkage disequilibrium in this case, the normalized LD coefficient $D'$, or the squared-correlation $R^2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can occur if the **Ab** genotype is [lethal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lethal_allele), i.e. you won't observe individuals with a **Ab** genotype.

Allele lethality is a common mechanisms that can explain non-mendelian inheritance of a trait.

For the question of which LD metric to use, this is tricky. Under the assumption that allele lethality is indeed at play, you observed perfect haplotypes, so *D'=1* wouldn't be incorrect. Yet the correlation coefficient is also correct in the sense that SNP A is not a perfect proxy for SNP B.